# How to run same process with passing different parameter?

Tags: shell-script

i try to run the below command at the same time but only first one can run but second one get blocked by same process id.

```
sh ./controller.sh $myfile/a.sh start '1' 'today'
sh ./controller.sh $myfile/a.sh start '2' 'early'
```

controller.sh

```
progpath=$1
prog=$(basename $progpath)
get_pid() {
    echo "`ps -ef | grep $prog | grep -v grep | grep -v $0 | awk '{print $2}'`"
}
  local pids=$(get_pid)
  if [ -n "$pids" ]; then
    echo "$prog (pid $pids) is already running!"
    return 0
  fi
```

How can i run the 2 command successful by changing the controller.sh?

Comment: Can't you just use `start-stop-daemon` or `pgrep` or `pidof` or `ps -C`?

Answer (score 0):

Your script has several issues. I don't comment this here. Just give you a better approach using `lockfile` from `procmail` package:

```
progpath=$1
prog=$(basename "$progpath")

LOCKFILE="/tmp/$prog-$2-$3.lock"
lockfile -r0 "$LOCKFILE" || exit
...
# remove the lockfile when script exits
rm -f "$LOCKFILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prog=$@

pids=$(ps -ef | grep "\"$prog\"" | awk '{print $2}')


if [ -n "$pids" ]; then
    echo "$prog (pid $pids) is already running!"
    return 0
    fi
```

Comment: whosoever tagging the answer as non-useful, please mention the reason for that also.